# Windows Update: Does Windows record which updates are installed? If so, where?

Tags: windows, windows-update

Particularly interested in Windows XP, but all versions of Windows would be useful (if they differ).

**EDIT:** How does Windows/Windows Update know what to apply and what it has already done? Does it compare .dll/.exe versions or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just come across the following Microsoft web page which sheds some light on the question: [Command-line switches for Windows software update packages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262841)

Under the heading, *Overview of the installation process*, it states:

> - **The [hotfix] installation program registers the software update under one of the following registry keys:**
>
>   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Updates\<operating system>\<service pack level>\KB<nnnnnn>`
>   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Hotfix\Q<nnnnnn>`
>   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Hotfix\KB<nnnnnn>`

and

> - **Removal information for the software update is stored in a hidden folder named:**
>
>   - `$NtUninstallQnnnnnn$` or `$NtUninstallKBnnnnnn$` in `%Systemroot%`

Answer (score 3):

There is a log file located at `%windir%\Windowsupdate.log` which should have all information about updates performed on the system. Alternatively you could check the Add/Remove programs dialog and check off the **Show Updates** checkbox to see which ones are installed.

[image]

Comment: However, WindowsUpdate.log can be deleted. So can the %WINDIR%\Software Distribution\ directory which contains WU downloads. Add/Remove Progs doesn't seem to contain all updates (for example, the Malicious Software Removal Tool).

Answer (score 1):

When you click on Windows Update in XP, you'll see a link to view your update history.

[image]

Comment: Interesting - I never knew you could review this here. However, it doesn't necessarily list all WU.